# Input value 0 = empty?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, null

I have a page where you register your dog, and I want all these fields to be required:

```
$required_fields = array('name', 'age', 'gender', 'breed', 'size');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields marked with * are required.';
        break 1;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that if someone enters 0 (which I instruct them to do if the dog is a puppy), the submission seems to read that field as empty (giving me this error). I have checks further down removing any none integers etc., but the best solution and easiest form for users I still think is having them being able to enter 0 as a value. Anyway, is there any way I can make my php code read the value as not null?

Comment: Have you tried testing for `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

A fix you may consider would be to do somethng like this:

```
if ((empty($value) && $value != 0) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
```

Comment: Yeah that´s what I was hoping would not be the case, but I guess I have to accept it since all sources seem to point to that. Thanks for the answer, I guess i´ll solve the problem by just not having the age be required and setting it to 0 (puppy) if empty.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP treats these as empty:

```
null
0
""
"0"
false
```

So you have two choices. Append something to it, like value `a0` or, use `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `$value === null`

```
if ($value === null && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
```