# Magically Undefined Index php

Tags: php, undefined-index

I am currently completing php a practice assessment and my browser tells me that variable "quan" on line 4 is undefined. My Programming Teacher is stumped as to what is wrong as my code seems to be correct.

Here is the error message I am receiving:
Notice: Undefined index: quan in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpassesment/shopping list/list.php on line 4

Html Form Page:

```
    <form action="list.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Shopping List</legend>
Name:    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="McLovin Juskinsky" pattern="[a-Z]{2,30}" autofocus><br>
Item:    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="olive oil" pattern="[a-Z]{2,30}"><br>
Quantity:<input type="text" name="quan" placeholder="0" pattern="[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100]"><br>
<input type="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP results page:

```
<?php
$yourName = $_POST["name"];
$yourItem = $_POST["item"];
$yourQuantity = $_POST["quan"];
echo "<h1>Welcome " . $yourName . "<h1>";
```

everything about this code works except "quan" is undefined for some unknown reason. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: everything seems to be correct. Try restarting your web server.

Comment: Try closing the web browser down and reloading the page. Also check that you are loading the correct file this has caught me out a few times :-S

Comment: There is no variable named `quan` in the code you presented. Please provide the exact error message you receive. Also check the developer console and verify the form data being sent.

Comment: Also `[1-100]` is allowing `1` or `0`. Try `min` and `max` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), or write out the longer regex version `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)`.

Comment: Possible duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571391/input-value-0-empty

Comment: @JorgeSB There is no `empty` usage in the code provided here, if there was it wouldn't throw the error described.

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: try to remove pattern of quan and see the results, and always validate the input using PHP

Comment: @chris85 the validation of variables is required, because PHP not require a variable declaration and in some cases where a variable is set with a value as zero, empty string or null,  is necesary this task.

Comment: @JorgeSB None of that relates to the usage of `empty()`. Please look at the error and the code the OP provided again.